# How to expire guest users after 1.5 hours logged in?

Tags: users, wp-cron

I want to pre create a table of users 1-200
Then after login for the first time it

---

Edited to be further explained & described:
I'm trying to issue access to all pages for a guest user with a defined (set) timing of 90 minutes after the first login.

### I want to create N guests users. After each user logs in for the first time; the user is granted 90 minutes to explore the web freely. After the time has finished the user could be deleted/changed password or whatever works easier.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe a better way is to 'expire' the access codes after xx time. The access code could have a datestamp embedded (in the same method as a password). Your process would decode the access code and compare the embedded datestamp with current time If within allowed time, allow the code to work.
But your question is very thin on details.

Comment: Hello Rick, thanks for trying to help me out.

To give a solid start... I don't have any experience coding, just learnt basics on youtube. 

I built a wordpress page where only members can get access to it. Later I was requested to add this "temporary users" where they can only access the page for 90 mins. 

Hope this clarifies it a bit.

Answer (score 0):

In your `single.php` template file:

```
<?php
if (has_post()) {
    the_post();

    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    $hasPermission = in_array('subscriber', $user->roles);
    // or maybe instead of a role, you can check for your custom permission:
    // $hasPermission = current_user_can('view_access_codes');

    $postTime = get_post_time('U', true);
    $timeThreshold = time() - 60 * 60 * 1.5;
    $hasTimePassed = $postTime < $timeThreshold;

    if (!$hasPermission && $hasTimePassed) {
        status_header(\WP_Http::FORBIDDEN);
        ?>
        Only registered users can view this page.
        <?php
    } else {
        // print the post
    }
}
```

or with the PHP [DateTime object](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php):

```php
$postDate = new \DateTime(get_post_time(DATE_W3C));
$postDate->modify('+90 minutes');
$hasTimePassed = $postDate < new \DateTime();
```

Beware that the post still can be accessible by other means, such as [the REST API](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/) or your [RSS feed](https://wordpress.org/support/article/wordpress-feeds/). For these I'd recommend using the [`the_content` filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/the_content/).

Comment: Doesn't your code allow access to a post xx minutes after the post is published? But doesn't limit access to the post (whenever it was published) for xx minutes (which is what the OP apparently wants)? Example: if post was published in  1 July 2019, readers could only access it on for 24 hours after that date, assuming the post had an 'expiration' of 24 hours.

Comment: Say we have a post published at 4:30 and it's supposed to be available to guest for 1 hour and indefinitely for subscribers, `$postTime = 4:30`. Let's say it's 5:00 - `$timeThreshold = 5:00 - 1 hour = 4:00`, therefore `$hasTimePassed = 4:30 < 4:00 = false`. Time hasn't passed yet, the right side of the `if` statement is false. After one hour, it becomes `true`.

If user has permission, the whole condition evaluates to `false`, showing the content. If user doesn't have permission, time is checked instead.

Comment: But that's not what the OP wants (as I read it). My impression is that he wants the equivalent of a coupon code that will last for xx hours after being issued. But it could be that he wants the page that displays the codes to be available only for xx hours after the page is posted. In which case, your solution would work.
The question really needs to be expanded, which is probably why it got a downvote. And why my interpretation of the OP question might be wrong.

Comment: I agree, the question is unclear at best. I believe my post answers the question, but your interpretation probably makes more sense in real-world implementation.

Comment: Hello @ericek111 & Rick sorry for the unclearness of my post and thank you for taking the time to help me out. 

As Rick described best. I'm trying to issue access to all pages for a user with a defined (set) timing of 90 minutes after the first login.

So to explain further I want to create 5 guests users. 
After each user logs in for the first time is granted 90 minutes to explore the web freely. After the time has finished the user could be deleted/changed password or whatever works easier.